# css background images are not showing in chrome but working on atom live server

Tags: html, css, image, background

in my project images are not showing in chrome web browser but working properly in atom live server,
image location- \Documents\myapp\images
CSS folder location-\Documents\myapp\style.css

this is how i'm directing an image - background-image:url('../images/img1.jpeg');

Comment: Can you please upload screenshot of your browsers console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
background-image:url('../images/img1.jpeg');
```

Use: `background-image:url('images/img1.jpeg');`

Your CSS file is in `\Documents\myapp\style.css` and image file inside `\Documents\myapp\images`, From `CSS` file you do not have to go back to parent folder using `../`

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked, can u tell me why the previous one didn't worked.

Comment: Well lucky you I happened to skip past that directory part and yes you are right he has css in parent folder

Comment: While using `../` the control or the search for required file goes to the parent directory from where you are searching. In your case it gone to `myapp` & search for `images` folder there & that made it wrong.

Comment: @Rishabsharma '.. /' would make the browser search for the 'images' folder in the 'document' folder as your css file is already in 'myapp' folder

Comment: if my explanation helped you & if you think its helpful to other please mark it as resolved.

Comment: @Sinto thankyou for ur explanation , i marked ur answer as resolved

Comment: @Rishabsharma no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a caching issue, try press `F5` while holding `shift` button

Comment: Nope I guess its cross origin issue